# Node JS requesting token using oauth2 not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, oauth-2.0

I am unable to get back a token by using the simple 'request' npm module for oauth token authentication.

```
var request = require('request');

var payload = {
    'grant_type': "password",
    'username': user,
    'password': pass,
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'scope' : "internal"
};

var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: host,
    headers: {
        //'accept': "application/json",
        'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    form: JSON.stringify(payload)
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var info = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(info);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
        //console.log(response.statusCode);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Getting back the following error:

```
 Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.rest.synthesio.com www.rest.synthesio.com:443
at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)


code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'www.rest.synthesio.com',
  host: 'www.rest.synthesio.com',
  port: 443 }
```

Any idea why am I getting a ENOTFOUND error? Not sure why it's not appending the full URL either.

These are the two parts of the URL:

hosturl : `'https://www.rest.synthesio.com/'`
tokenPath : `security/v1/oauth/token`

Please help. I tried everything!!!

Comment: I was able to do it with POSTMAN api tool but not through my JS code :( womp

Comment: Did you specify a protocol like 'http' or 'https' in your Node code?

Comment: @arjabbar Why would I need to specify http or https if I am using the 'request' npm module, instead of the http module? correct me if i'm mistaken. Thanks

Comment: I don't know. I never used request before. I just had to ask.

Comment: You definitely need the protocol/scheme in your URL for it to work. I confirmed that with request@2.72.0. I'm seeing DNS errors for that URL as well. Can you provide your Postman request headers and info in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Wow.... dumb mistake. I used `https://www.rest.synthesio.com` instead of `https://rest.synthesio.com`

Thanks for the help nonetheless guys!